# IIS for PHP php mail() sends spam

Tags: iis-7, php

I've setup my SMTP server yesterday on my IIS PHP server and configured my PHP.ini file accordingly and yesterday everything was working perfectly all my messages were getting delivered but today my messages are falling into spam folders, I don't know what went wrong do anyone have an idea why this can be happening?

Comment: It's getting crazy with all this duplications...

Comment: There's a lot of dupes for this question

Comment: I read all other posts they aren't the same like my problem. My code was working perfectly yesterday, I have no idea what went wrong in one night

Comment: It may be related to the amount of testing you did yesterday, certain mailservers may identify mail as spam if it's seen a lot of the same message from the same IP

Answer (score 0):

i think , your server may be at listed in Email Blacklist

check it out

[mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)
[whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check)

if not . then may be your mailing pattern may be of spammy, please wait for another 24hr or contact the server admin

Comment: it was showing on some certain addresses I removed them but still getting the same problem.

Comment: have you checked the content of the mail , it may have a spammy touch, have you checked the ip of your server in black lists  whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check
can you remember how many mails you have send yester day?